# How to scroll an html element both horizontally and vertically with top and side labels scrolling correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I want to scroll the purple area, while keeping the white dots aligned.
[image: scroll purple area, keeping white dots aligned.]

My current code has two related problems:

1. The blue rectangle is wider than the purple rectangle.
2. When moving the scroll bar all the way to the right (so that the dots go to the left), the dot in the purple rectangle moves a little further than the dot in the blue rectangle.

How do I fix these two problems?  My current code (html/svg/css/jquery) is below.

```
<html>
  <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <style>
      .c00 { overflow: hidden;  float: left;}
      .c01 { overflow: hidden;  width: 300;}
      .c10 { overflow: hidden;  height: 200; float: left;}
      .c11 { overflow: auto; width: 300;}

      .e11 { height: 200}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="c00">
      <div class="e00">
        <svg  version="1.1" width="100" height="100">
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>
          <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" fill="white"/>
    </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c01 horzLinked">
      <div class="e01">
        <svg  version="1.1" width="600" height="100">
      <rect width="600" height="100" fill="blue"/>
          <circle cx="300" cy="50" r="10" fill="white"/>
    </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="c10 vertLinked">
      <div class="e10">
        <svg  version="1.1" width="100" height="400">
      <rect width="100" height="400" fill="green"/>
          <circle cx="50" cy="200" r="10" fill="white"/>
    </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c11 vertLinked horzLinked">
      <div class="e11">
        <svg  version="1.1" width="600" height="400">
      <rect width="600" height="400" fill="purple"/>
          <circle cx="300" cy="200" r="10" fill="white"/>
    </svg>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script>

$(function(){
    $('.vertLinked').scroll(function(){
        $('.vertLinked').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());    
    })
})
$(function(){
    $('.horzLinked').scroll(function(){
        $('.horzLinked').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());    
    })
})

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because scrollbar width will be included in div width so you will find the blue rectangle content is wider than purple rectangle content
To solve this issue you have two solutions

1- Make purple rectangle wider than blue one by adding scrollbar width to its width only if the purple rectangle is horizontally overflowed

2- Deduct scrollbar width if scrollLeft is greater than rectangle width

here is code for solution 2

```
<html>
  <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <style>
      .c00 { overflow: hidden;  float: left;}
      .c01 { overflow: hidden;  width: 300px;}
      .c10 { overflow: hidden;  height: 200px; float: left;}
      .c11 { overflow: auto; width: 300px;}

      .e11 { height: 200px}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="c00">
      <div class="e00">
        <svg  version="1.1" width="100" height="100">
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="red"/>
          <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" fill="white"/>
    </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c01 horzLinked">
      <div class="e01">
        <svg  version="1.1" width="600" height="100">
      <rect width="600" height="100" fill="blue"/>
          <circle cx="300" cy="50" r="10" fill="white"/>
    </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="c10 vertLinked">
      <div class="e10">
        <svg  version="1.1" width="100" height="400">
      <rect width="100" height="400" fill="green"/>
          <circle cx="50" cy="200" r="10" fill="white"/>
    </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c11 vertLinked horzLinked">
      <div class="e11">
        <svg  version="1.1" width="600" height="400">
      <rect width="600" height="400" fill="purple"/>
          <circle cx="300" cy="200" r="10" fill="white"/>
    </svg>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script>

$(function(){
    $('.vertLinked').scroll(function(){
        $('.vertLinked').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());    
    })
})
$(function(){
    $('.horzLinked').scroll(function(){
        var scrollLeft;
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.scrollLeft() > $this.width())
            scrollLeft = $this.scrollLeft() - getScrollbarWidth();
        else
            scrollLeft = $this.scrollLeft()

        $('.horzLinked').scrollLeft(scrollLeft);    
    })
})

function getScrollbarWidth() {
        var $inner = $('<div style="width: 100%; height:200px;">test</div>'),
            $outer = $('<div style="width:200px;height:150px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; visibility: hidden; overflow:hidden;"></div>').append($inner),
            inner = $inner[0],
            outer = $outer[0];

        $('body').append(outer);
        var width1 = inner.offsetWidth;
        $outer.css('overflow', 'scroll');
        var width2 = outer.clientWidth;
        $outer.remove();

        return (width1 - width2);
    }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmwz9/BUv5n/)

Comment: Mohamed - Thanks for your explanation and solution.  It fixes problem #2 that I described above, which is the more serious problem of the two. With your solution, it is impossible to move the horizontal scroll bar all the way to the right, so now the white dots in the blue and purple rectangle remained aligned. That's very good. Your answer also has a nice function for computing the width of the scroll bar.  I'm wondering if I can use that to make the blue rectangle the same width as the purple rectangle.  I think I'll investigate that possibility and perhaps fix my problem #1 also.

Comment: Edited comment: Mohamed - Thanks for your explanation and solution.  It fixes problem #2 that I described above, which is the more serious problem of the two. With your solution, it is impossible to move the horizontal scroll bar all the way to the right, so now the white dots in the blue and purple rectangle remained aligned. That's very good. Your answer has a nice function for computing the width of the scroll bar.  I'll investigate your first proposed solution also, which may fix my problem #1.

Comment: You can try solution 1 if horizontal scrollbar appears on purple rectangle by checking div.scrollWidth > div.clientWidth

Comment: Using Mohamed's suggestion, I was able to determine the width of the scroll bar and adjust the size of the rectangles accordingly.  I also found that using a <table> gave me better control over the layout of the rectangles.